# Seed Random in Opal

Tags: random, opalrb

Is there a way to seed a random number generator in Opal? `srand` doesn't seem to do anything, and using the `Random` class directly errors out with `NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Random`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment.

There's an open PR that should fix this, but it's kinda stalled

https://github.com/opal/opal/pull/657

Would need someone to pick up and complete the work that was started.